# Passing arguments in ajax event JSF action listener

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I want to trigger an action everytime I click on an ace:checkBoxButton.

This is my code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
     <ui:repeat value="#{controller.targetValues}" var="target" varStatus="metadata">
         <ace:checkboxButton value="#{controller.isTargetChecked(target)}"/>
     </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

After that, I want to pass my var variable to the listener method.

**UPDATE:** my problem is that the method in the value attribute is triggered every time the checkbox button is rendered or refreshed. 
So I need a method that is called only when I click on the checkbox button.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You forgot to tell which problem exactly you have with this XHTML code, because it looks fine. Perhaps the actual problem is in the Java code?

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I have updated my question

Comment: I'm not familiar with ICEfaces, but if it follows the same rules as standard JSF buttons, then I would expect that the `value` attribute only shows the button's value and that you should be using `action` attribute to specify the action. Consult the ICEfaces documentation to be sure.

Comment: I do it, but I don't understand how to pass parameters to the action function.

Comment: The syntax as you have is fine, but the result of the expression in the `value` attribute is used to show the button value (as you would see on webpage), not to invoke the action.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add an ajax event to the checkbox like this:

```
<ace:checkboxButton id="checkBox" value="#{controller.isTargetChecked(target)}">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{controller.method}" uptade="@this" />
</ace:checkboxButton>
```

so the ajax is triggered when something is changed (there are other events but there is no complete list :-( ). `method` is called when something is changed and `uptade` is not necessarily but if you edit the checkbox it will be uptaded.

Comment: Read tne comments by BalusC. The problem is there. No in a missing akax tag